# django urls keeping the last path

Tags: django, forms, url, path

so i have this 2 forms

```
<form action="adicionar" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="searchbutton" type="submit"> Adicionar<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</form>

<form action="novo">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2> Bem vindo {{ user.getNome }}</h2>
    <input type="text" name="txtPost">
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

and these views

```
def novo(request):
 texto = request.GET.get('txtPost')
 user = request.session['usuario']
 p = Post(texto=texto, fk_user=user,likes=10)
 p.save()
 usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id=user)
 return   posts(request,id_user=usuario)

def adicionar(request):
 nome = request.GET.get('txtSearch')
 usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id=request.session['usuario'])
 amigo = Usuario.objects.get(nome=nome)
 a = AmigoTemp(id_user=request.session['usuario'], id_amigo=amigo.id)
 a.save()
 return posts(request,id_user=usuario)
```

the only relation between them is their .html file, which is the same
everytime i click in any of the buttons to call their respective function in the views, they just clone the last path

for example: i'm on my localhos..../
i click on the searchButton to call the 'adicionar' method and my url is now

localhost.../adicionar
i do what i gotta do and get back to localhos.../, but when i click on the another form i get this url

localhost.../adicionar/novo

and if i click again, just keep cloning like:

localhost.../adicionar/novo/novo

and so on...

i don't really know if made my problem clear enough, but i dind't find anything about it

my urls.py is this:

```
url(r'^autentificacao/novo/',novo),
url(r'^autentificacao/adicionar/',adicionar),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action is attribute `<form action="novo">` is relative. So browser will keep adding those to current url.

You need to make these absolute url. For that its better to name your urls and use them in template.

For example,

```
url(r'^autentificacao/novo/',novo, name='novo'),
url(r'^autentificacao/adicionar/',adicionar, name='actionar'),
```

Then in template,

```
<form action="{% url 'novo' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2> Bem vindo {{ user.getNome }}</h2>
    <input type="text" name="txtPost">
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```